# What does "putt forward" mean? Or did I hear it wrong?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

So I am doing a camp for vision impaired kids where I play movies for them with audio description on. The other day I played the animated film *Hotel Transylvania 2*.

Some kid asked me about a line in the audio description. I listened to it several times, and couldn't make out what it says. The scene is Dracula and the gang ride on a scooter that inches forward because it is overloaded. To my ear, the line sounds like "The monster scooter putts forward." But what does "putt forward" mean? If the verb is not "putt", what could it be?

The audio excerpt can be found [here](https://clyp.it/gllgqpap).

Comment: Compare https://www.google.com/search?q=%22train%20chugged%20forward%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard meaning of **[putt](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/putt)** is:

> a stroke in golf that you make when the ball has reached the green in an attempt to get the ball in the hole.

But in **[Onomatopoeia](http://www.noisehelp.com/examples-of-onomatopoeia.html)**, *'putt'* is used to describe a sound, much like a '*woof*' or a '*boom*'.

> **Putt** (*Onomatopoeia*): A regular sound characterized by the sound of "putt putt putt putt...", such as made by some slowly stroking internal combustion engines. (See: *Etymology 2*)

Source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/putt (See *Etymology 2*)

In this context, the noise made by the scooter is described bu the '*putt*'-ing sound.

What is ***Onomatopoeia***?

> *Onomatopoeia* is a word that phonetically imitates, resembles or suggests the sound that it describes

Here's more on *Onomatopoeia* :

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia
- http://www.dictionary.com/browse/onomatopoeia

Comment: Oh that explains everything. I didn't know putt was an onomatopoeia.

Comment: I didn't know either. But a little research taught me something new, thanks to you.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The weird thing is I actually googled "putt forward", "putts forward", and "putted forward", and got nothing.

Comment: @edcool One thing to try when searching returns nothing is to change the group of words you're searching for "putts forward" is unusual, but "scooter putts" returns a few clues.